# Is there a text based mysql UI?

Tags: mysql, user-interface, terminal, frontend

I don't mean the standard mysql-client CLI, but rather something similar to what [midnight commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) is to filesystem management. The simple command history of the basic cli is not bad but really doesn't cut it when testing more complex query, and the layout of the data isn't that great. PHPMyAdmin is useful and all, but it's ugly and requires a lot of mouse usage.

OS: linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[dbext.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=356) provides DB access from within Vi. It provides things like stored connections, schema browsing, command history, some auto completion, and bind variables.

I assume there is something similar for Emacs.

Comment: Wow access through Vim, I would upvote this 100x! Gonna try it asap

Comment: Pretty awesome isn't it.

You could make it the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Well not exactly what I had in mind, but I'm trying it now and it is indeed pretty cool.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but just in case neither of the above solutions have worked for you I would like to recommend [Mitzasql](https://vladbalmos.github.io/mitzasql/) - a simple text based Mysql client which gives you a quick read-only access to the database, data manipulation can be done through regular sql queries.

**disclaimer** - I am the author of said tool.

Comment: It's awesome. Thanks lot.

Answer (score 0):

In emacs, there is a build in mode M-x sql-mysql.

You will be prompted for a user name, password, schema name (or database name), and the server name.

From then on, when one opens a .sql file, emacs should bind that .sql file to the *SQL* buffer associated with the MySQL session.

Inside that mode you can get help with a "Control-H m" keystroke.

There is a family of emacs sql- modes.  They all pretty much work the same.