# MySQL - command line table browser

Tags: mysql

Is anyone aware of a command line GUI for browsing MySQL table data where phpMyAdmin isn't available?

I'm happy using the mysql command line client but it would be neat if there was something quicker to navigate.

==== EDIT

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the answers. But what I'm looking for is a command line GUI. i.e. something that I can run on the remote server using a command like `mysql-gui`.

The main problem is that remote access to the MySQL port is locked down. But I can probably get a Linux program installed.

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Lots of answers here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-MySQL-client-for-Mac-OS-X-or-Windows and I organized the recommendations into an answer wiki.

Comment: For commandline text based 'ui' mysql/mariadb access there are answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168437/is-there-a-text-based-mysql-ui

Answer (score 1):

You can check out DBeaver or MySQL workbench(NIX/WIN)

Answer (score 1):

HeidiSQL is another good browser with command line functionality